# Raid 0 performance vs Raid 5 with n+1 disks

Tags: raid

In short, can similar performance be expected from a Raid 5 with n+1 disks as with a Raid 0 with n disks?

If not, can someone explain why?

If I understand correctly, Raid 5 distributes the xor data also across all disks, so I'd expect similar performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **read** access, a RAID5 is expected to have similar performance to a RAID0, in theory even a bit better if the access is seek-time bound.

For **write** access in a random pattern, RAID5 is expected to perform much worse than RAID0 - here is why: Consider changing a single block in an n+1 RAID5, and due to the random nature of the access no other blocks in that stripe are in cache. Now the RAID controller has to

- Read all other data blocks in that stripe (n-1 blocks)
- Calculate the new parity block
- Write the new data block and the new parity block

i.e. for a total cache miss, a single write in RAID0 translates into n-1 reads and 2 writes for a RAID5. Even if the complete stripe is in cache, you still end up with 2 physical writes for each logical write.

RAID controllers try to mitigate that by keeping the parity block in battery-backed RAM, so that when another write hits the same stripe, the parity block is written only once. If the access pattern is very random, this still results in a major performance penalty.

**EDIT**

From the comments I take it, that I didn't elaborate enough on the problems inherent with writing the parity block: These have 2 points of focus

- To make the inconsistency windows as small as possible, writing the changed data block and writing the changed parity block must occur as closely together in time as possible - this greatly reduces the amount of optimization possible.
- While the parity block and the data block are written to different disks and thus can go parallel, the parity disk is also in use for the other requests. So while it can parallelize with the current request, it will serialize with the next and previous. It does not matter, that another stripe might use another parity disk - in this case the parity write of one request is serialized with data access in another request.

Comment: I can see how writing a single block is much slower than with RAID 0, because the controller has to read the bits from the other disks to compute parity.

However, I assume that the disks contain at the same stripes adjacent blocks, writing would not require to read back existing bits except for the start and end block, correct?

Also, since the logical write goes to two disks rather than 1, I wouldn't expect it to be slower

Comment: See my edit for a more thorough explanation!

Comment: @EugenRieck, your second addition about writing parity data ("While the parity block and the data block are written to different disks and thus can go parallel, the parity disk is also in use for the other requests. So while it can parallelize with the current request, it will serialize with the next and previous.") is not what happens in a RAID 5 as it uses a distributed parity scheme. Adjacent data block writes will therefore cause parity block writes to different disks and _can_ be parallelized (if there are enough disks). It still has a much larger write penalty than RAID 0.

Comment: @StarCat This concurrency still happen! The parity disk for one stripe is a data disk for another, so writing the parity of one request serializes with writing **data or parity** of another (depending on the distance of the stripes). I'll add that to the explanation.